# How do I check for each value of an element with Prototype JS and change it if equal zero?

Tags: prototypejs

I have a page which lists a bunch of products and their prices.

And all the price tags look like this:

```
<span class="price">....</span>
```

I want to check each one of those elements, see if it's equal to $0.00 (text) and if so, then replace it with a specific text message instead of showing the zero price.

How do I write that in Prototype JS? Totally new to this and can't figure it out.

Thanks.

I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
if($$('.price') == "$0.00"){ $$('.price').update('some text'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$$()` function returns an array, so you cannot (successfully) compare it to a string.  Likewise, arrays do not have an `update()` function so `$$('.price').update(...)` would never work.

---

If you're using Prototype version 1.7 then you can do this:

```js
$$('.price:contains("$0.00")').invoke('update', 'some text');
```

Again `$$` returns an array but I use [`:contains("$0.00")`](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation) to filter the contents because it avoids writing a loop.  Then [`Enumerable#invoke()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/) calls `'update'` on every returned element, which also avoids writing a loop.

---

For versions earlier than 1.7 you cannot avoid at least one loop so this is probably the neatest way:

```js
$$('.price').each(function(span) {
    if (span.innerHTML == '$0.00') {
        span.update('some text');
    }
});
```